# Count row values in excel pivot table with drop-down selector

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have a table where I store nodes and the versions of the installed packages in them.

[image]

I want to create a pivot table where I can see the number of the occurrence for each version. And I can select the package from a drop down list in the left-top corner of the table which refresh the table data (the version numbers too, not just the count value).

[image]

Can I do this in Excel 2016, and if yes, then how?

Comment: actually in your example you don't have `1.0.1`, you have `1.01`. And you don't have `1.0.2`, you have `1.02`. Is it right? Your worksheet must count `1.02` as `1.0.2` ?

Comment: No, it's 1.01 and 1.02, I misspelled it. The values under the selected package are the values in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-organize your source data to be in the following format ...

```
Node No Package Name    Package Version
Node 1  package 1   1.01
Node 1  package 2   3.0
Node 1  package 3   1.1.9
Node 1  package 4   
Node 2  package 1   1.01
Node 2  package 2   3.0
Node 2  package 3   
Node 2  package 4   3.0
Node 3  package 1   1.02
Node 3  package 2   
Node 3  package 3   1.2.0
Node 3  package 4
```

Then you can set up a Pivot table that will match the layout you are looking for ...

[image]

Which can be filtered at A3.

---

**Edit to demonstrate how to set up ...**

[image]

Comment: Could you describe how to create a pivot table like this from the rearranged data?